# converting ID events to void events

Tags: objective-c, void

Is it possible to convert this:

```
- (id)initWithFrame : (NSRect)frame 
{
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame])
    {
        [self setFont:[NSFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:0.0]];
      //  [self startTask];
}
    return self;
}
```

to make it a void?

thanks,
Elijah

Comment: Well this starts when the app opens. I want to start this after. Trigger it by ibaction or something.

Comment: This isn't an event, it's a method.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Ok, well, like I said, this starts after the app opens, and starts the task, and displays the output. BUT, if I take out start task, and trigger it from another .m file when I press a button, it doesn't print the output of the task. So this code above is necessary to start this correctly. Is there a way to NOT make it start when the program starts? and have it "trigger-able"?